# ¿Cómo cambiar valor Booleano por texto en Python - Django?

Tags: python

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Hola colegas, tengo hecho un pequeño proyecto en Python Django, pero en esta parte de la tabla en vez que diga True o False, aparezca Activo e inactivo respectivamente. He realizado varios If, pero no he tenido solución. Una ayuda. He puesto los If en las views, no se si este haciendo mal. Gracias

Comment: Si `var` es tu variable boolean, la expresión `"Activo" if var else "Inactivo"` produce lo que pides. ¿Era eso?

Comment: Eso iría en las views? Ejecute, pero sigue sin cambios.

Comment: ¿Podrías [edit] tu pregunta y mostrar lo que intentaste hasta el momento? No olvides leer [ask].

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar **["Inactivo","Activo"][bool]**

por ejemplo

```py
mybool = True
print(f'estado = {["Inactivo","Activo"][mybool]}')

//Resultado...  "estado = Activo"
```

Comment: La variable estado es la que almacena los valores booleanos